# MVC2 code conversion in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using someones code for paging. His code is in MVC 2 and I want it in MVC3 Razor. Problem is with syntax.

Below is the code in mvc need someone to fix syntax for razor please.

**Problem is in this line**

```
IList<Customer> customers = (IList<Customer>)Model.Data;
```

//Can't use Model.Data directly.  Doesn't pick up generic type.

```
IList<Customer> customers = (IList<Customer>)Model.Data;
  foreach (Customer item in customers) { %>
<tr onclick="onRowClick(<%= item.ID %>)">
  <td>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID}) %> |
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })%>
  </td>

  <td>
    <%= Html.Encode(item.ID) %>
  </td>

  <td>
    <%= Html.Encode(item.FirstName) %>
  </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line could be translated like this:

```
@ {
    IList<Customer> customers = (IList<Customer>)Model.Data;
}
```

and then:

```
@foreach (Customer item in customers) {
    <tr onclick="onRowClick(@item.ID)">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
            @:|
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>

        <td>
            @item.ID
        </td>

        <td>
            @item.FirstName
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I would also benefit from this migration to improve this code. Currently you are using loops in your views which are ugly and could be replaced with display templates.

So, in your main view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Data)
```

and in `~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Customer.cshtml`:

```
@model YourApp.Models.Customer
<tr onclick="onRowClick(@Model.ID)">
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID })
        @:|
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ID })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.ID
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.FirstName
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. There is parser ERROR on @: |  error is = ":" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Comment: @pirzada, it seems that you are not using the latest RC2 version. Try this instead: `<text>|</text>`

Comment: Thanks I understand that. One last thing How I convert this in Razor.  <h2>@Model.IsAdd ? "New Customer" : "Edit Customer"</h2>   . Its just print false ? "New Customer" : "Edit Customer"

Comment: @pirzada, this is already Razor. Could you show the original code? Also have you verified the value of `IsAdd`? Is it true or false?

Comment: Value is false. Thats the only code as you see in output its printing false. Output = false ? "New Customer" : "Edit Customer"

Comment: @pirzada: try this: `@if (Model.IsAdd) { <text>New Customer</text> } else { <text>Edit Customer</text> }`.

Comment: Here is something related to @:|
I just download MVC3 RC2 and installed but still not parsing @:|
I have VS2010 beta SP1 installed may be its not recognizing or creating problem.

Comment: This is working. Why? @if (Model.IsAdd) { <text>New Customer</text> } else { <text>Edit Customer</text> }

Comment: @pirzada, why what? Why is it working? It's because that's the correct syntax :-) I would really suggest you reading some tutorials about the Razor view engine syntax.

Comment: Thanks alot. I read all the time :) but still need to learn more on daily basis.

Comment: by the way if I write condition in textbox or beginform its working fine. Like @Html.TextBox("Customer.ID", Model.Customer.ID == 0 ? "" : Model.Customer.ID.ToString())